# Dreamspark/MS Imagine VS 2013 PRO multiple installations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dreamspark

i got Visual Studio 2013 Pro from Dreamspark around 2 years ago and am still a student at my college today. i got a new laptop and a desktop and wish to install VS on both, this would bring up my installations to 3 devices. i've googled around how many times i can install VS on different devices and the responses have been varied. some say 1, some say 2 some say as many as you want. i dont want to breach any rules here so i was wondering if i could install my copy on my new devices without problem or if i should just download 2015 for the them. and if i do go for VS 2015, which should i pick. enterprise or community or what?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just start using the 2015 Community Edition personally.

From [Microsoft's VS Community Edition page](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/), under "Usage":

> "For Individuals": Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.

and

> "For organizations": An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.

So I'd say that if you use it in he same way you use(d) Dreamspark's version, you're covered a couple times: Personal, non-profit apps, plus you're using it in a learning environment (meaning the school itself could distribute it to everyone for class/course usage).

I have it installed on multiple computers, all linked to the same MS account, no problems; nothing weird had to be done to accomplish it. :)